# Is there a good proof that all the polynomials in this family are irreducible?

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials

Writing the few lines below in PARI/GP, one easily checks that the polynomials

$$(X^3-4019680)-(a_2X^2+a_1X+a_0)$$

are all irreducible over $\mathbb Z$ when $a_0,a_1$ and $a_2$ are integers between $0$ and $20$. Is there a computer-free (or more illuminating) proof of this fact ?

ff3(a2,a1,a0)=1-polisirreducible(x^3-(a2*x+a1*x+4019680+a0))

vv1=vector(21^3,k,7)

for(a2=0,20,for(a1=0,20,for(a0=0,20,
vv1[(21^2)*a2+21*a1+a0+1]=ff3(a2,a1,a0);););)

check=sum(k=1,length(vv1),vv1[k])

Comment: irreducibility of some of these polynomials you can prove with [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion)

Comment: @ pedja : right, it works for some but not all. I'm looking for a criterion like Eisenstein's that might apply to all of them at once.

Comment: I know for Perron's and Cohn's criterion but I don't think that you can apply them on these polynomials...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sketch.* Because the constant term is so large relative to the other terms, possible integer roots of such a polynomial lie in the relatively small interval $[160, 165]$ far to the right of the origin. The fact that $X_0$ is a root is equivalent to $4019680$ having a representation in base $X_0$ with particularly large coefficients, and by writing $4019680$ in the corresponding bases we see that it doesn't have such representations.

*Proof.* Reducibility is equivalent to the existence of an integer root. By inspection the polynomial can have at most one real root $X_0$, somewhere past $\sqrt[3]{4019680} = 159.0000131...$. By setting $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = 20$ we check numerically that $X_0 < 166$, so the only possible roots are $X_0 = 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165$. Any integer root must divide the constant term, but:
$$4019680 \equiv 0 \bmod 160$$
$$4019680 \equiv 154 \bmod 161$$
$$4019680 \equiv 136 \bmod 162$$
$$4019680 \equiv 100 \bmod 163$$
$$4019680 \equiv 40 \bmod 164$$
$$4019680 \equiv 115 \bmod 165.$$

Since $0 \le a_0 \le 20$, it is impossible for $X_0$ to divide the constant term unless $X_0 = 160, a_0 = 0$ or $X_0 = 161, a_0 = 7$. In either case, after dividing out by $X_0$, $X_0$ must divide the new constant terms, which are $-(25123+a_1), -(24967+a_1)$ respectively. But
$$25123 \equiv 3 \bmod 160$$
$$24967 \equiv 12 \bmod 161$$

and again since $0 \le a_1 \le 20$, this is impossible.

Comment: Very nice Qiaochu! I have the bad habit of relying too much on my computer, so I tend to forget simple proof techniques like this one.

Answer (score -2):

If you are really interested only in $0 \leq a_i \leq 20$, write the polynom as product of two polynoms of degree 1 and 2 with unknown coefficients:

$(A x^2 + B x + C)(Dx + E) = ADx^3 + (BD+AE)x^2+(BE+CD)x+CE$

If I did it correct, this yields for any B, C, E:

- $E \cdot C = a_0 - 4019680$
- $C + B\cdot E = a_1$
- $E+B = a_2$

But these euqations are not solveable for $0 \leq a_i \leq 20$.

Comment: I understand nothing in that solution. What are $B,C$ and $E$ ? Also, a polynom of degree 3 is irreducible iff it has no root.

Comment: Sorry, I improved the answere a little bit.